# Can our hand pass through a table?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, estimation, quantum-tunneling

I recently [read](https://archive.is/ymJos) that "there is a $1$ in $5.2^{61}$ chance that the molecules in your hand and table would miss each other, making your hand go through it". To me, it seems completely false, considering electron repulsion and the high density of solids. But, considering my lack of knowledge in quantum mechanics, is it actually possible for this to happen by treating everything as waves?

Comment: Although I don't doubt the reliability of the source, can you cite the same?

Comment: @ManasDogra Maybe it's [this].(https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/comments/fh2366/thanks_to_quantum_tunneling_there_is_a_15261/) The wording seems to be the same but there are people in the comments arguing its wrong saying that is the probability of two atoms passing through each other. Or it could be [this](https://twentytwowords.com/true-facts-crazy-false/?utm_source=googlesearch). And despite the quotation marks, i couldn't find any research papers however

Comment: I reckon that the authors key point is that there does not (!) exist a law in physics that two massive objects tunnel through each another.

Comment: First, it should be pointed out that these type of ridiculous scenarios are not restricted to quantum mechanics. One could say, for example, that there's a probability that everyone on Earth will trip at the same time. There's a nonzero probability thermal energy from the ground could align itself to spontaneously shoot you into space. All of these are possible in classical mechanics, _given certain assumptions that we can't test_. The real problem here is not quantum mechanics but probability. Frequentism starts to fall apart...

Comment: ..., and we instead have to resort to Bayesianism by talking in terms of _ignorance_ of things rather than _frequency_ of things. We don't know if quantum mechanics even holds for stupiditly small probabilities, so many assumptions can fail in our extrapolations.

Comment: 5.2 to the power of 61? That's a funny way to say 10^43 or so.

Comment: It is unlikely, but possible for the atoms of your hand to pass through the table, but it is even more unlikely in this case that the atoms of your hand would remain "atoms of your hand".

Comment: 1 in 10^43 is a stupid overestimate. Try 10^(10^43).

Comment: I suspect it was meant to be 5.2x10^61 (or 5.2e61), and either the OP or the source they quoted got it wrong.

Comment: I think the original estimate neglected the fact that the atoms of something embedded in a solid or dense fluid are localized exponentially at the scale of nanometers. A true estimate is probably beyond e^(-10^7),

Comment: Counter question, can you go to a casino, and get a billion times billion times 26 coming up in Roulette? Theoretically yes, but in reality never.

Comment: Would be interesting to model this as a constant force barrier separating regions of zero potential. The force in question might be proportional to the young's modulus, width of five an inbound particle momentum comparable to your average karate chop. 
You can avoid the math and raise the odds a lot higher if you use a sledge hammer instead.

Comment: The concept of "Practical impossibility" is relevant. If an event is so improbable that it would be unlikely to occur anywhere in the visible universe, in the lifetime of the universe, then for all practical purposes, it can be considered impossible.

Comment: @AdilMohammed: I am very sure that it is either [the webpage you found](https://twentytwowords.com/true-facts-crazy-false) (which is the earliest source that Google brings up) or where that webpage author got it (which supposedly was from some reddit user called "bulletking119" (but this user's earliest reddit message is from 2019-may so something is fishy here). Either way, the wording is the same so that's the best we have unless the asker tells us the exact source.

Answer (score 34):

In my opinion, that source is very unreliable.

Firstly, it totally fails to paint a proper picture. The reason is that although quantum tunneling is possible, the likelihood of your **entire hand staying in one piece** but tunneling through the table is ridiculously far smaller than (say < 1/10<sup>1000</sup> times) the likelihood that a small number (say 2) of molecules from your hand tunnels through the table but the others stay on the expected side. So why on earth should we concern ourselves with the likelihood of "our hand passing through the table" if it is nowhere near the second-most likely outcome, or third-most likely, or ...? Your simple classical intuition is perfectly fine, even from a quantum mechanics perspective, because the phrase "your hand" does not refer to a completely precise set of particles anyway so it is really ridiculous to consider quantum tunneling of a few particles 'in' your hand.

Secondly, particles do not "miss each other" when quantum tunneling happens. That phrase is very misleading because it suggests that the particles are like tiny solid objects and they need to 'miss' in order to 'pass'. No, not at all. The wave-function of any particle **always** extends beyond any finite potential barrier. Whenever you perform a measurement, you are essentially just manipulating the environment to make the particles you are measuring have wave-functions that have a single sharp peak (corresponding to your measurement result). This peak location may lie outside the classically expected region, but it is **not** because the particle *passed through the barrier*! It simply **localized** beyond the barrier!

Comment: Thirdly (but I didn't check), it seems like the purported one in $5·2^{61}$ really comes from assuming the particles involved are simply tiny uncharged balls....... If one uses QM to compute the likelihood of your hand staying in one piece and tunneling through the table (say 2 cm of wood), it's certainly going to be less than one in $10^{1000}$...

Comment: If you want an analogy for the last paragraph, tunneling is more like teleportation -- you're on one side of the barrier, and then suddenly you're on the other side, but you never actually travelled through it. The wavefunction just collapsed differently.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, though I would like to refrain from using that word because the particle was **always** on both sides until forced to localized. It was never only on one side to begin with, which is a **far too common misconception**.

Comment: I recall using Earth/Jupiter Gravity well to set up the barrier and something with a transponder and asked about observing it while it's in transit and which law got broken.

Comment: To add to this, there's an infinitessimally small chance that every molecule in your body will tunnel to the centre of the sun... But it ain't going to happen before the universe either implodes or rips itself to bits

Answer (score 22):

The basic frame of the world we live  in is quantum mechanical. In quantum mechanics the atoms molecules lattices are modeled with wavefunctions, i.e. solutions of specific wave equations, that give the probability of an interaction to happen.

Also in quantum mechanical systems there is a probability, once the wavefunction is known, of [tunneling through a barrier](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html).  Your hand going through the table would fall into that category.

[image: tunneling]

The table and the hand are composed of order of $10^{23}$ ([Avogadro's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) number) atoms and molecules. In order for your hand to tunnel through one coherent wave function should describe the table and one your hand, so that there could be a probability for tunneling. The number of molecules show how improbable this will be, and I guess something like this was used to get the numbers quoted.

Comment: One should add that additional to the chance that the hand tunnels through , there are all the other minimal chances that something horrible happens with the hand instead of just tunneling trough the table ....

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Well yes, if coherence stops halfway , for example :). Fortunately all this are in the infinitesimal probability cases.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp Obviously, the number of states in which the atoms tunnel through and form a hand on the other side are astronomically smaller than the total number of states where they tunnel through.

Comment: This answer's conclusion can make it sound as if the number quoted by the OP *was* derived by some sound computation which I suppose you don't consider it to have been.

Comment: @JirkaHanika I talk nowhere of "sound". The wavefunction is the **quantum mechanical wavefunction** by which probabilities are calculated

Comment: I understand.  I'm just worried that you are giving an "in principle" answer and then suggesting that those same principles were or could have been used to get the numbers quoted.  Whereas it's more likely that somebody simply counted the molecules and didn't bother themselves with wavefunctions.  The numbers quoted strike me as ridiculously, uncomprehensibly, naively *high* if words like "hand" or "table" are supposed to retain their everyday meanings.

Comment: @annav "sound" is an adjective that means "based on reason, sense, or judgment"

Answer (score 17):

*To me, it seems complete false . . . . . .* and that is due to you being unable to comprehend the scale of $1$ in $5.2^{61} \approx 5\times 10^{43}$.

Since the Big Bang approximately $4\times 10^{17}$ seconds have elapsed.  Now that is a big number but nowhere as big as $5\times 10^{43}$ but the suggested half life of a proton $5\times 10^{41} \,\rm$ is not so far away.

In this context the unit [micromort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromort), a unit of risk which represents a one in a million chance of sudden death, might help.

[image]

Can you really comprehend the chances of your hand passing through a table and that it means that if you tried the experiment you might have to wait for much longer than the age of the Universe for it to happen?

Comment: The given probability still sounds way too high to me. Even if an individual particle has a generously estimated probability of 1/2 to tunnel through the table, a naive assumption of independence would provide a probability around $2^{-10^{23}}$, much lower than the stated figure.

Comment: What a terribly misleading data visualisation :/ Did they just size those bars completely arbitrarily? (Compare the hegiht of the 37,932 bar with 463...)

Comment: @SteveBennett Might it not be a logarithmic scale as if often the case in such graphs? If that was the case the ratio should be $1.7\,:\,1$.

Comment: @Magma - Even your purposefully naïve estimate could still turn out far too high if it turns out that those independently tunneled particles no longer form a hand.  Or even too low: consider alpha decay.  Staying together could be energetically favored for certain composite particles such as Helium nuclei or human hands and so you can't assume independence, not even for an upper bound or for a lower bound.  But I agree that the OP contains a number that's *obviously* way too high, so as to betray the source's completely false understanding of quantum tunneling.

Comment: Matt Parker (of youtube standup maths fame) introduced the wonderful "mankind-century-second" (or something along those lines) unit: If 10 billion humans try something every second for a hundred years, that adds up to between $10^{19}$ and $10^{20}$ attempts, so $10^{-20}$ serves as a nice probability boundary for "things that may have actually happened to someone."

Answer (score 7):

I think the point being made, if there indeed is one, is that you can at least in principle calculate the probability that every atom in the hand/table system moves at the same exact moment in exactly the right direction and distance so as to allow the hand to pass through the table without their wavefunctions tripping over each other.

Consider now that the age of the universe is about 4.36 x 10^17 seconds and compare that to the probability cited.